# Solution ASP.net call method from url to view pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to call a method to view a PDF
I am attempting to call the method from the URL eg. `/Home.aspx/ViewPDF`

The ViewPDF in the url is the method in the Home.aspx file.

I am new to ASP and this has stumped me, thanks if you can provide any help

**EDIT 1:**
I have an asp button with this in it's click method and it works:

```cs
    protected void test12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        string FilePath = Server.MapPath("/Tasks/Content/54874/dummy.pdf");
        WebClient User = new WebClient();
        Byte[] FileBuffer = User.DownloadData(FilePath);
        if (FileBuffer != null)
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-length", FileBuffer.Length.ToString());
            Response.BinaryWrite(FileBuffer);

        }
    }
```

How would I be able to make the same thing happen from visiting `/Home.aspx/ViewPDF`
with /ViewPDF being a method inside the code behind of Home.aspx
I believe the method needs to be static to be able to view it from the url is there any alternative for defining the file path as `Server.MapPath` is not static.

I have made a test method in Home.aspx:

```cs
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public static string test(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        return "test";
    }
```

But when I visit /Home.aspx/test it just loads a version of the page with no images and slightly off css

Thanks for any help

**Edit 2 / Solution:**
After doing a bit of looking around on google you can easily implement MVC into web forms
https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2013/12/30/so-you-inherited-an-asp-net-web-forms-application.aspx

From that I made a controller

```cs
    public FileResult GetTaskAttatchment()
    {
        string ReportURL = Server.MapPath("/Tasks/Content/54874/dummy.pdf");
        byte[] FileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(ReportURL);
        return File(FileBytes, "application/pdf");        
    }
```

Which now works perfectly, Thanks again for all the help

Comment: If you are new to Asp.net web forms don't use that. That's a legacy system now. You should use .net core MVC instead of .net framework. [More about this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/overview?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: Here is a sample code in Asp.net https://www.aspsnippets.com/questions/112991/Create-WebService-to-read-PDF-from-folder-and-download-using-C-and-VBNet-in-ASPNet/

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I currently have and MVC controller that can show me the PDF from the URL, However the rest of my project is in web forms so I have had to create a new project, is there anyway of including the controller into my original web form?

Comment: Yes I did in a project but that was way back. So it's very much possible to use.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look around now see if anything shows up

Answer (score 0):

//check your datatype for attachment shuld be varbinary...

protected void btnfinalupload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
        string filename = "";
        string filenameret = "";
        using (DataSet ds = GetFormForDownload(id,finid))
        {
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                filenameret = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["attachment"].ToString().Trim();
                filename = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["filename"].ToString().Trim();

                byte[] bytes;
                string fileName, contentType;
                bytes = (byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["attachment"];
                contentType = "application/pdf";
                fileName = filename;
                Response.Clear();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.Charset = "";
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                Response.ContentType = contentType;
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
                Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
        }
    

}
```